# Swift - NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this Swift code (migrated from Obj-C)

```
 NSOperationQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
    print("WORKING...")
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        print("FINISHED")
    })
})
```

The mainQueue block doesn't execute ("FINISHED" is never printed). What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please show me the Objective-C code.

Comment: `NSOperationQueue * opq = [NSOperationQueue new];
    [opq addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"WOKING...");
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"FINISHED");
        }];
    }];`

Comment: Actually, your code is working fine for me. Where is this being executed?

Comment: I'm executing it in the "applicationDidFinishLaunching" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is perfectly fine and both the operation block executing but the `mainQueue` operation block sometimes takes lil time to execute because `mainQueue` adds that block to the operation queue of the main thread but does not guarantee when it will be executed. There could be other items in that queue still waiting to execute.

Comment: You're right! There was another process in another class that was executing before the "mainQueue" block, so it was blocking the other one! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use GCD e.g:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    [weak self] in
    self.collection.reloadData()
}
```